# Параллельное выполнение скрипта

Tags: php

**Написан следующий скрипт.** 
Из директории CMS "вырывается" большое колличество изображений, средствами php каждое обрезается, уменьшается размер и всё это помещается во временную директорию, названия картинок генерируются случайно и это всё затем выводится на странице из временной папки, при последующем запуске скрипта временная директория полностью очищается от файлов и всё начинается заново. Вопрос - как поведёт себя скрипт при одновременном обращении к нему, скажем 100-а человек, будут ли корректно выводиться изображения?

Answer (score 1):

> > как поведёт себя скрипт при одновременном обращении к нему, скажем 100-а человек, будут ли корректно выводиться изображения?

Естественно, нет =) Будут перетираться изображения и грузиться другие.

Предлагаю добавить к пути папку. То есть, при обращении:

- создается папка $dir = 'tmp/'.session_id()
- в нее заливаются картинки
- вывод

А вот дальше бубен (мы не знаем, когда картинки выведутся, может, там диал-ап). Варианты:

1) выводить через [img src="data:[...]"](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL) и сразу удалять (грустно, вроде до 4кб размер)

2) давать минуту-две-etc времени. Т.е. что-то такое

```
<?
session_start();
$limit = 60 * 2; // 2 min
$now = time();
foreach (scandir('tmp') as $dir)
  if (($dir != '.') && ($dir != '..') && is_dir('tmp/'.$dir)) { // сканим все папки
    list($time, $id) = explode('_', $dir, 2); // и если
    if ($now - $time > $limit) // возраст больше лимита
      rmdir_rec('tmp/'.$dir); // рекурсивно очищаем + удаляем, в гугл за функцией
    }
$dirname = $now.'_'.session_id(); // в эту папку будем кидать картинки

require 'main_script.php'; // основной скрипт
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

А не проще ли в таком случае отображать изображения через скрипт, по принципу капчи? Все равно GD нагружать - так хотя файловую систему не нужно будет трогать.
Если не секрет, для чего все эти хитрые манипуляции?

Comment: Эти манипуляции пришлось делать  в связи с требованием заказчицы, согласно которым фотографии должны выводиться обрезанными и сжатыми. Времени для хитроумного решения уже не оставалось, пришлось быдло-кодить. На самом деле в перспективе даже одновременное обращение 10 человек к скрипту на этом сайте вряд ли возможно. Тем не менее хотелось что бы всё работало более-менее стабильно. Может сделать проверку размера временной папки и только по превышении определённого лимита очищать всю директорию?

Comment: Тогда можно создать кучу миниатюрок, а потом выводить их через скрипт в зависимости от get параметра. В адресе картинки всегда будет значиться php скрипт, зато нагрузка на GD практически сойдет на нет.